# How to add/retrofit birdstop to tile roof without removing tiles?

Tags: roof, pest-control, roofing

Is it possible to add "birdstop" to the edges of a Spanish tile roof without having to take the tiles off? Is there something on the market that can be screwed to the facia?

Comment: In the old days we cut lead sheets and tacked them in place. Today I use a plasma cutter and cut galvinised flashing not something many home owners have. What about some spray foam? Just enough to fill the area but not so much that could lift the tiles.

Comment: Interesting. I considered foam but rodents can chew through it right? Even if not, there's a lot of linear footage to the roof edge. I imagine I'd need dozens and dozens of cans of foam to make that work. Do you know of any pre-cut sheets on the market? Or individual closures I can push into each opening?